# Determine the largest 3-digit prime factor of ${2000 \choose 1000}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Determine the largest 3-digit prime factor of ${2000 \choose 1000}$.

I could not approach the problem at all. I have no idea how to try the problem. Please help.

Comment: The largest prime less than 1000 is 997.  Does it divide your number?

Comment: @vadim123 No, I think not.

Comment: What is the prime number that appears exactly twice in $1001\cdots 2000$ but exactly once in 1000!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that if $p$ is a prime such that $667 \leq p \leq 1000$, then $ p$ is not a factor of $ {2000 \choose 1000}$. Use the fact that $667 \times 3 > 2000$.

**Hint:** Try the next largest prime number $p^*$. Does it work?

Comment: This is a brilliant observation and one of the main ingredients of Erdös' famous [proof of Bertrand's postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate).

Answer (score 2):

To find the solution, I need to find a number that comes exactly thrice in $2000!$ but exactly  once in $1000!$ as, $3-2=1$. We get the $2$ as $1000!$ occurs twice. So, such a number is the prime just below $666$ which is $661$.

Comment: This was my exact thinking process. However i got stuck for a while thinkin whether 661 is a prime... anyway for ascertaining the fact easily?

Answer (score 1):

[Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem), says that the number of factors $p$ (prime) in a binomial coefficient $\binom{a+b}a$ equals the number of carries produced while performing the addition $a+b$ using base$~p$ representation of integers. Since the question only considers prime factors $p<1000$, the representation of $1000$ in base$~p$ contains at least two digits; moreover if $p>500$ the first digit will be$~1$. Now the only way $1000+1000$ can produce a carry in base$~p$ for $500<p<1000$ is if the (equal) final digits do so, and for that their digit value should be larger than $p/2$. This means that $1000>p+p/2$, which gives $p<\frac23\times1000<667$. Moreover, for values of $p$ close to that upper bound one will have $1000\bmod p=1000-p>p/2$, so it suffices to search for the largest prime number $p<667$.